# ClassCastException casting chronometer.java file

Tags: android, kotlin, classcastexception, milliseconds, chronometer

I'm using Kotlin. I tried using the Millisecond Chronometer found here https://github.com/antoniom/Millisecond-Chronometer. I downloaded the zipfile, and then copied the Chronometer.java file into a new .java file in my project.

I placed a chronometer widget in the layout file and gave its id chrono

When I tried to use Chronometer.java, it throws me an error:

```
val mChronometer = findViewById<Chronometer>(R.id.chrono)
//Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Chronometer cannot be cast to com.example.rinor.chronometertimer.Chronometer
```

How to fix this? I'm sure if I get this line right everything else is smooth sailing from there on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you use the wrong Chronometer in your .xml `<Chronometer>...</Chronometer>` instead of

```
<com.example.rinor.chronometertimer.Chronometer
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">...
</com.example.rinor.chronometertimer.Chronometer>
```

Comment: Thanks. I made edits in the xml with com.example.rinor.chronometertimer.Chronometer and it worked! Though I still saw that the timer shows 00:00:0 instead of 00:00:00 which still doesn't look stopwatch-y enough. Does anyone has experience in using this custom widget and tell me how to add an extra zero at the end of the display?

Comment: That should be a new question. Change `text += Integer.toString(milliseconds);`to `text +=  df.format((milliseconds);` in your file. Maybe you need to change the calculation for the milliseconds too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you import "**android.widget.Chronometer**" instead of "**com.example.rinor.chronometertimer.Chronometer**" change the import.

Comment: It trys to cast to the correct one, the problem probably is in xml.

Comment: This is a good step too. Actually naming the .java file Chronometer is not a good practice as I realized. I should have named it CustomChronometer to differentiate more easily.